# What are some ways to post python pandas dataframes to slack?

Tags: python, pandas, slack

How can I export a pandas dataframe to slack?

df.to_json() seems like a potential candidate, coupled with the slack incoming webhook, but then parsing the message to display as a nice markdown/html-ized table isn't obvious to me.

Long time listener, first time caller, please go easy on me...

Comment: This is slightly broad this question but I generally just copy the output from ipython and then post as code using triple ticks

Answer (score 9):

There is a .[`to_markdown`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_markdown.html)() method on DataFrames, so that might work.  But if you are just looking to cut and paste, [Tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) is a good choice.  From the docs:

```
from tabulate import tabulate
df = pd.DataFrame([["Name","Age"],["Alice",24],["Bob",19]])
print tabulate(df, tablefmt="grid")
```

Returns

```
+---+-------+-----+
| 0 | Name  | Age |
+---+-------+-----+
| 1 | Alice | 24  |
+---+-------+-----+
| 2 | Bob   | 19  |
+---+-------+-----+
```

Paste that in a code block in Slack and it should show up nicely.

Answer (score 6):

Slack doesn't seem to take arbitrary HTML input or format text with escaped newlines which limits to plain text. `tabulate` as suggested in another answer works, but if you want something that is self contained this would work. Assuming your data frame is in `df`

1. In python terminal session, jupyter notebook, or print statement run something like `print(repr(df))`.
2. Copy the output
3. Paste in code blocks in slack.

For the data frame I had on hand this is what you would enter in the slack chat box before hitting enter.

````
```
   code    sid state        triplet
0  SCAN   2057    AL   2057:AL:SCAN
1  SNOW    ABY    CA    ABY:CA:SNOW
2  SNOW  15A21    MT  15A21:MT:SNOW
3  COOP   0010    ID   0010:ID:COOP
4  SNOW  1F01A    BC  1F01A:BC:SNOW
```
````

If you wanted to integrate this as a web service replace the copy/paste stuff with web services/hooks.

Comment: One common mistake could be using single  `  instead of  ``` for multiline code block with line breaks in Markdown.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone looking to query a Postgres database table and send the output in a nice tabular format to slack.

**Postgres DB Connection module**

```
def dbConnect (db_parm, username_parm, host_parm, pw_parm):
    # Parse in connection information
    credentials = {'host': host_parm, 'database': db_parm, 'user': username_parm, 'password': pw_parm}
    conn = psycopg2.connect(**credentials)
    conn.autocommit = True  # auto-commit each entry to the database
    conn.cursor_factory = RealDictCursor
    cur = conn.cursor()
    print ("Connected Successfully to DB: " + str(db_parm) + "@" + str(host_parm))
    return conn, cur
```

**Slack Broadcast to Channel module**

````
def slackBot(self, message):
    webhook_url = self.slack_incoming_webhook
    slack_data = {"text":"``` " + str(message) + " ``` <!here>"}
    header = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    response = requests.post(webhook_url, json=slack_data,headers=header)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise ValueError(
            'Request to slack returned an error %s, the response is:\n%s'
            % (response.status_code, response.text)
          )
````

**Prepare Slack Message module**

```
def prepareSlackMessage(self, cur):
        from tabulate import tabulate
        query         = "SELECT something_awesome FROM my_awesome_table"
        print query
        out         = dbQuery(cur, query)
        if len(out) > 0:
            df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(out), index=None, dtype=object)
            df_tab  = tabulate([list(row) for row in df.values], headers=list(df.columns), tablefmt="grid", stralign="center")
            print df_tab
        else:
            df_tab = "Nothing to post, the database query didnt return any result"
            print df_tab

        return df_tab
```

[Sample output message in Slack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAEAN.png)